# Does the backplane on an HP server have any impact on the speed of the drives?

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, sas, sata

I have an HP Proliant DL380 Gen7. The server currently has no drives and is running on the integrated smart array controller. I was looking into replacing the controller with an LSI-9211-8i controller and adding some SATA III (6gbps) drives. I know the controller and the drives will work together but I am not sure if the backplane that the drives connect to will actually cause any kind of incompatibility.

The original spec with the server was SATA II (3gbps) / SAS 6G so thats my concern.

If there is an issue, is there anyway to resolve it?

Comment: Did you ever get to test it? If yes, what were your findings?

Answer (score 0):

On a DL180G6 / SE326M1 with 25x2.5" . I tried 4 raid controllers, all work fine but the backplane is limiting sata drives/ssd to sata II ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't even understand the question here... but SATA disks in that server will downshift 3Gbps because of the controller. But it shouldn't matter unless you're using SATA SSDs.